# How to create a Behavior based component in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I have a number of objects on my screen that I change the opacity of, and to make this opacity change animated instead of instantaneous, I add this `Behavior` to each of the objects:

```
Behavior on opacity {
    NumberAnimation {
        duration: 500
        easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
    }
}
```

I am attempting to create a component for this. I've created a file named `FadeBehavior.qml` with these contents:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3 as Controls

Behavior on opacity {

    id: fadeBehavior

    NumberAnimation {
        duration: 500
        easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
    }

}
```

Then, instead of adding the `Behavior` to each object, I'm adding:

```
FadeBehavior { }
```

But this is not working (sorry I can't add more information than "not working" - this is an inherited app and I have not been able to run it in debug mode; when I make a mistake in my QML file, all that happens is that my window comes up as a blank one-inch square).

It seems as if the `on opacity` in the first line is the part Qt doesn't like. In `FadeBehavior.qml` `on opacity` is underlined in red, expecting token `{`. Is there some other syntax for specifying the name of the property the `Behavior` is attached to?

Comment: You can't really do this, `Behavior` is a "special" QML element, even its syntax is an exception in the QML language paradigm. I personally don't like that, especially the lack of an alternative way to specify the target, I have found this to be very liming on many occasions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one work around that would work.

Subclass all of the standard types that you need (`Rectangle`, `Item`, `Image`, etc.) like this

```
Item {
    Behavior on opacity {
        NumberAnimation {
            duration: 500
            easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
        }
    }
}
```

Save this as *MyItem.qml* and change every `Item` to `MyItem`.

Answer (score 0):

With Qt 5.15+ you can make a component based on behavior.
The following example exists in the official document:

```
// FadeBehavior.qml
import QtQuick 2.15

Behavior {
    id: root
    property Item fadeTarget: targetProperty.object
    SequentialAnimation {
        NumberAnimation {
            target: root.fadeTarget
            property: "opacity"
            to: 0
            easing.type: Easing.InQuad
        }
        PropertyAction { } // actually change the controlled property between the 2 other animations
        NumberAnimation {
            target: root.fadeTarget
            property: "opacity"
            to: 1
            easing.type: Easing.OutQuad
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.15

Text {
    id: root
    property int counter
    text: counter
    FadeBehavior on text {}
    Timer {
        running: true
        repeat: true
        interval: 1000
        onTriggered: ++root.counter
    }
}
```